# Backspace key not working after clicking okay button of swal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have written below lines of code

```js
$(".only-numbers").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    swal({
      title: "Warning",
      type: "warning",
      text: "Please enter Numbers only"
    });

    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});

$("#driver_contact_number").on("keyup keydown change", function(event) {
  var max_chars = 12;
  if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) {

    swal({
      title: "Warning",
      type: "warning",
      text: "Number should not exceed 12 digits"
    });


    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<input id="driver_contact_number" class="only-numbers">
```

Whenever user enters greater than 12 digits, the swal warning message gets displayed but after clicking ok button of swal popup, then when we click on backspace, it does not work. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should check keyCode (del, backspace) before displaying warning message.

```
if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 46  && $(this).val().length >= max_chars)
```

2) You should focus your input on swal close event.

```js
         $(".only-numbers").keypress(function(e){
                    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) 
                    {
                        swal({
                        title: "Warning",
                        type: "warning",
                        text: "Please enter Numbers only"
                        }).then(function() {
                $(e.target).focus();
              });

                         return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
               }); 

         $("#driver_contact_number").on("keyup keydown change", function (event) {
            var max_chars = 12;
               if (event.which != 13 && event.which != 8 && event.which != 46  && $(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 

                    swal({
                        title: "Warning",
                        type: "warning",
                        text: "Number should not exceed 12 digits"
                     }).then(function() {
               $(event.target).focus();
             });


                 $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
               }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<input id ="driver_contact_number" class="only-numbers">
```

Comment: I am not getting it... please help me by providing code segmenr

Answer (score 1):

After you dismiss the alert, you can utilize the promise to focus back where you came from.

Other changes:

- I don't know why you had the else in but I removed it as not needed.
- you had a deprecated `type` so I changed it to `icon`
- Your length function had >= but should be > which was causing the issue with backspace

```js
$(".only-numbers").on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    swal({
      title: "Warning",
      icon: "warning",
      text: "Please enter Numbers only"
    }).then(function() {
      $(e.target).focus();
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});

$("#driver_contact_number").on("keyup keydown change", function(event) {
  var max_chars = 12;
  if ($(this).val().length > max_chars) {
    swal({
      title: "Warning",
      icon: "warning",
      text: "Number should not exceed 12 digits"
    }).then(function() {
      $(event.target).focus();
    });
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<input id="driver_contact_number" class="only-numbers">
```

Comment: It is displaying warning message when we click on backspace... please help

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell precisely without a working example, but I would say that when you click on the "ok" button of the alert, your input is not focused anymore so the backspace doesn't work.

You could probably fixed that by setting the focus to your input after the "ok" is clicked (there are some methods like swal.DismissReason.close in the documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-dismissals)